# AFNetworking POST to Woocommerce

Tags: json, xcode, wordpress, api, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a product on Woocommerce using the Woocommerce v2 api and AFNetworking. Here is my code:

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clientappdownload.com"];
   NSDictionary *authDict = @{@"consumer_key":consumerKey,@"consumer_secret":consumerSecret};

   NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
   AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:sessionConfig];

   [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
   [manager setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];

   [manager POST:@"https://clientappdownload.com/NobleCents/wc-api/v2/products" parameters:authDict success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"success %@",responseObject);
   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"fail %@",error);
   }];
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
fail Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x7ffbfb419b80 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ffbfb6418a0> { URL: https://clientappdownload.com/NobleCents/wc-api/v2/products } { status code: 404, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 104;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 29 Dec 2014 16:46:38 GMT";
    Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=500";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = Apache;
    "Set-Cookie" = "PHPSESSID=lldn4nq9fmmokrj19dd04rqvl5; path=/";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clientappdownload.com/NobleCents/wc-api/v2/products, com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b226572 726f7273 223a5b7b 22636f64 65223a22 776f6f63 6f6d6d65 7263655f 6170695f 61757468 656e7469 63617469 6f6e5f65 72726f72 222c226d 65737361 6765223a 22436f6e 73756d65 72204b65 79206973 206d6973 73696e67 227d5d7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404)}
```

Please help me out.